# Как массив в типе данных строки перевести обратно в тип данных массив?

Tags: php

В шаблоне получаю массив, но он в типе данных строки, пытаюсь преобразовать его в тип данных массив, но не получается:

```
$a = '[12,3,4]';
$arr_a = (array) $a;

echo $arr_a[0];
```

Он мне выводит это:

```
[12,3,4]
```

Хотя по идее, мне надо чтобы вывел 12.
Как строку оформленную в виде массива перевести в обратно в тип данных массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$resultArray = json_decode($a, true);
```

ещё можно так:

```
$resultArray = explode(',', trim($a, '[]'))
```